# Latex enumerate: making first item italic

Tags: enumerate, italic

I have an enumerate-list and want to make the first item in this list (including the number) italic. It seems like I can make everything italic except the first number - otherwise the whole list crashes. Here are some minimum examples:

This one works

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textit{dsfdsf
    \item adsadasd}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This one also

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item dsfdsf
    \textit{\item adsadasd}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But this one doesn't

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
    \textit{\item dsfdsf
    \item adsadasd}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Why does the last one crash the list and what could be workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First `\item`s are processed a little differently. Rather change the font shape using a switch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
  {\itshape\item dsfdsf}
  \item adsadasd
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```